# Xaf Actions with the duplicate 'ShowNavigationItem' identifier are detected

Tags: c#, xaf

I have a module that my main module uses. Main module's codes are unreachable so I can't intervene its structure. I added a ShowNavigationItemController to my module and I copied my module to the main module's bin directory. When I run the main module I get "Actions with the duplicate 'ShowNavigationItem' identifier are detected in the 'Sms.Module.Controllers.CustomShowNavigationContollerSettings' and 'Xpand.ExpressApp.Security.Controllers.ShowNavigationItemController' controllers. How can I fix it and make things work ?

Answer (score 0):

I´m afraid your main module and Xpand module can't live together in the same project in the current state. Have a complete review on this behaviour at https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T191034.

Here are some solutions for your case.

If you, or someone else, can touch main module code:

- Inherit your CustomShowNavigationContollerSettings from Xpand controller, and that means make your main module Xpand dependent.
- Change main module implementation, if possible. Instead of override actions, handle it's events, using Frame.GetController < T > (). Once done, you will no longer have the "ShowNavigationItemController descendant seat" taken by your code. See how to do it in: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18055

If you cannot touch main module code:

- Just let one go. Remove Xpand or your main module.
- You will catch up with main module code later, and now what you need is just a work around. In this case, you can disable either main module controller, or Xpand controller, at your own risk. One way to remove a single controller, it's to create a descendant of it in your module, and set the descendant TargetViewId to "none".